# "Object not callable" error if I specify a parameter when trying to retrieve value

Tags: python, parameters, properties, setter, getter

When I try to retrieve the value of a property, and include a parameter, I get an "object is not callable" error message.

When I get the value, I want to optionally specify "refresh" as True to force the value to be relearned from my host instead of using the value stored in my variable.  For example, if I say `a = x.host_name(refresh=True)` I want the hostname to be retrieved from the host instead of pulled from the variable `_host_name`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7

import netaddr

"""
test.py - Used for testing

"""


class Host():
    """
    Represents a Host device

    Attributes:
        host_name: str
            Name of host
        manage_address: IP
            Managment IP address of the host
    """

    def __init__(self, host_name="", manage_address=netaddr.IPAddress("0.0.0.0")):
        """
        The constructor for the Host class.

        Parameters:
            host_name: str
                Host name of the host
            manage_address: ip
                Management IP address of this host
        """
        self._host_name = host_name
        self._manage_address = manage_address

    @property
    def host_name(self, refresh=False):
        """
        The host name configured for this host device

        Paramters:
            refresh: bool
                Should we relearn the hostname if we already know it?

        Returns: str
            Host name defined on the host
        """

        if refresh:
            # TODO: Get hostname from the host
            pass

        return self._host_name

    @host_name.setter
    def host_name(self, host_name):
        """
        Set the host name of the host

        Parameters
            host_name: str
                The host name to configure on the host

        Returns: None
        """
        self._host_name = host_name

    @property
    def manage_address(self, refresh=False):
        """
        The IP address to manage the host

        Paramters:
            refresh: bool
                Should we relearn the IP address if we already know it?

        Returns: IP
            Management IP address of the host
        """

        if refresh:
            # TODO: Get management IP address from the host
            pass

        return self._manage_address

    @manage_address.setter
    def manage_address(self, manage_address):
        """
        Set the management IP address of the host

        Parameters
            manage_address: IP
                The management IP address of the host

        Returns: None
        """
        self._manage_address = manage_address


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # A host object
    h = Host()
    h.host_name = "myhost.com"

    print(h.host_name)   # Works
    print(h.host_name(refresh=True))   # str object is not callable error
    print((str(h.manage_address(refresh=True))))   # IPAddress object is not callable error
```

My guess is that I am not allowed to pass a parameter when getting the value from a property... but if that's the case, how do I conditionally get a value?

Comment: You can't pass parameters to a property access, that doesn't make sense. As the error tells you, you end up trying to call the value the property returns. If you need parameters, make it a regular method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is what I though, but I don't understand how I would create the equivalent of a getter and a setter using regular methods.

Comment: ...remove the decorator and prepend get_ and set_?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I've come up with as my solution:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7

import netaddr

"""
test.py - Used for testing

"""


class Host():
    """
    Represents a Host device

    Attributes:
        host_name: str
            Name of host
        manage_address: IP
            Managment IP address of the host
    """

    def __init__(self, host_name=None, manage_address=None):
        """
        The constructor for the Host class.

        Parameters:
            host_name: str
                Host name of the host
            manage_address: ip
                Management IP address of this host
        """
        self._host_name = host_name
        self._manage_address = manage_address

    def host_name(self, refresh=False, host_name=None):
        """
        Sets and returns the host name of the host

        Parameters:
            refresh: bool
                Should we learn the value from the host even though we already know it?
            host_name: str
                Host name of the host

        Returns: str
            The host name of the host
        """
        if host_name is not None:
            self._host_name = host_name
        elif refresh or self._host_name is None:
            # TODO: Get hostname from host
            self._host_name = "thehost.com"   # Temporary

        return self._host_name

    def manage_address(self, refresh=False, manage_address=None):

        if manage_address is not None:
            self._manage_address = manage_address
        elif refresh or self._manage_address is None:
            # TODO: Get management IP address from the host
            self._manage_address = netaddr.IPAddress("127.0.0.1")   # Temporary

        return self._manage_address

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # A host object
    h = Host()
    h.host_name(host_name="myhost.com")

    print(h.host_name())   # Works
    print(h.host_name(refresh=True))
    print(h.manage_address(refresh=True))
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the same method to get the current value *and* set it to a new value. Why should `h.host_name()` *return* a value, instead of setting the host name to the default value `None`?